# Bash Script/Function

Tags: bash, git-bash

I'm trying to set up a bash function so that I can type a few parameters and create a git pull request:

```
gpreq "<title>" "<ticketnumber>" "<release>" "<briefdescription>"
```

I've tried both of these functions to no avail:

```
gpreq () {
    hub pull-request -m "$1\n\n Ticket: https://ticketsystem.net/issues/$2\n Target Release: $3\n Description: $4" ; }
```

and also

```
gpreq() {
    STR="${1}"$'\n\n Ticket: https://ticketsystem.net/issues/'$"${2}"$'\n Target Release: '$"${3}"$'\n Description: '$"${4}"
    hub pull-request -m "${STR}" ;
}
```

For some reason the line breaks don't seem to be working, instead the \n is coming through as actual characters. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What version is your bash (`bash --version`)? I have bash 4.3 and it handles the ANSI-C quoting perfectly.

Comment: Hmm, ANSI-C quoting was added to bash in verion 2.0 -- surely your bash version is more recent than that. (https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-4.4#n1754)

Comment: I'm using the Bash that comes with the Windows download of Git (https://git-scm.com/) - says it's 4.4.19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I don't know what hub is)

\n is a character that is converted by **some** command as a newline.

try inserting directly newlines

```
hub pull-request -m "$1

 Ticket: https://ticketsystem.net/issues/$2
 Target Release: $3
 Description: $4"
```

or use some function that interpred \n:

```
STR="$1\n\n Ticket: https://ticketsystem.net/issues/$2\n Target Release: $3\n Description: $4"
STR
hub pull-request -m "`printf "${STR}"`"
```

Comment: `printf ${STR}` leaves the variable unquoted, and it will destroy the whitespace formatting. Also, have to beware that the string may contain `%` characters with will cause printf errors. I don't recommend using printf without an explicit format string.

Comment: Worked great! FYI, hub is a wrapper for git for use on GitHub (https://github.com/github/hub).